# Set identity to several ZMQ servers, binded to same port

Tags: python-3.x, web, pyzmq

I am implementing a ZMQ DEALER-ROUTER pattern in Python 3.4. This [code from ZMQ guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:asyncsrv) is the core of my program. 

It sets identity for each client easily (ex. 1,2,3,4). However, if I start the same number of server workers, they are not paired with clients. One server worker may respond to clients with different identities.

My question is: **how do I set identities for each server worker, so that server worker 1 interacts only with client 1?** More precisely, I need 4 clients interacting with 4 server workers via one single port in a paired manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question. 
It is enough to modify previous code slightly to set up paired interactions:
**1. Pass id parameter in ServerTask Class to set server worker identity
 
2. Change backend from DEALER to ROUTER**

The whole system interacts in asynchronous pattern. I'll post the whole script:

```
import zmq
import sys
import threading
import time
from random import randint, random

def tprint(msg):
    """like print, but won't get newlines confused with multiple threads"""
    sys.stdout.write(msg + '\n')
    sys.stdout.flush()

class ClientTask(threading.Thread):
    """ClientTask"""
    def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id
    threading.Thread.__init__ (self)

    def run(self):
        context = zmq.Context()
        socket = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
        identity = str(self.id)
        socket.identity = identity.encode('ascii')
        socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5570')
        print('Client %s started' % (identity))
        poll = zmq.Poller()
        poll.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)
        reqs = 0
        for i in range(3):
            reqs = reqs + 1
            print('Client %s sent req #%d..' % (identity, reqs))
            socket.send_string(u'request #%d' % (reqs))
            for i in range(3):
                sockets = dict(poll.poll(1000))
                if socket in sockets:
                    msg = socket.recv()
                    tprint('Client %s received: %s' % (identity, msg))

        socket.close()
        context.term()

class ServerTask(threading.Thread):
    """ServerTask"""
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__ (self)

    def run(self):
        context = zmq.Context()
        frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
        frontend.bind('tcp://*:5570')

        backend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)      
        backend.bind('inproc://backend')

        workers = []
        for i in range(1,4):
            worker = ServerWorker(context, i)
            worker.start()
            workers.append(worker)

        zmq.proxy(frontend, backend)

        frontend.close()
        backend.close()
        context.term()

class ServerWorker(threading.Thread):
    """ServerWorker"""
    def __init__(self, context, id):
        threading.Thread.__init__ (self)
        self.context = context
        self.id = id

    def run(self):
        worker = self.context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
        identity = str(self.id)
        worker.connect('inproc://backend')
        tprint('Worker %s started' % identity)
        for i in range(3):
            client_ident, msg = worker.recv_multipart()
            tprint('Worker %s received %s from %s' % (identity, msg, client_ident))
            for i in range(2):
                time.sleep(1. / (randint(1,10)))
                worker.send_multipart([client_ident, msg])

        worker.close()

def main():
    """main function"""
    server = ServerTask()
    server.start()
    for i in range(1,4):
        client = ClientTask(i)
        client.start()

    server.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```